# Expand ContentPanel in AccordionLayoutContainer

Tags: java, gwt, gxt, gwtp

In my project I using **gwt 2.5.1** + **gxt 3.0.1** + **gwtp** (plugin for eclipse), and MVP - pattern.
I use *AccordionLayoutContainer* with 3 *ContentPanel*. When the application loads all panels collapsed.
How to make that one panel was expanded, depending on which parameter is specified in the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With:

```
navigator = new AccordionLayoutContainer();
navigator.setExpandMode(ExpandMode.SINGLE_FILL);
```

tells GXT to have only one panel open at one time.

And with `navigator.setActivePanel(widget);` you can set the active widget.